# GAE + JDO + JAVA + CRUD

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have created a simple application in GAE. This is my simple entity/JDO class

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Domain implements Serializable{
    @Persistent
    private String url;
    @Persistent
        private String aliasName;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
}
```

I am performing CRUD operation on this class. What i am doing is just add different object and then view that objects give option to delete and edit already created entities. When I click on the delete link against any entity in the view page. i just delete it. Issue is with me that after deleting that entity i redirect the user again to the view page so that user can see entity has been deleted. But when i see the view page again view page also show the deleted entity. means entity has not been deleted. If i refresh the page 3,4 times then after that entity didn't show. This is because entity has been deleted at first place but it take some time to complete this process. I want to know why i am facing this behavior of GAE?? If GAE or JDO is slow in performing CRUD operations. I am sharing my code for deletion of entity and for view all entities. Is there is any issue in my code please tell me.

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public List retrieveDomains() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMFSingleton.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Domain.class);
    List<Domain> list = null;
    List<Domain> detachedList = null;
    try {
        list = (List<Domain>) query.execute();
        detachedList = new ArrayList<Domain>();
        for (Domain obj : list) {
            detachedList.add(pm.detachCopy(obj));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        query.closeAll();
        pm.close();
    }
    return detachedList;
}

  public void deleteDomain(String name) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMFSingleton.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Domain domain = null;
    Transaction txn = null;
    try {
        txn = pm.currentTransaction();
        txn.begin();
        domain = (Domain) pm.getObjectById(Domain.class,name);
        pm.deletePersistent(domain);
        txn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if ( txn.isActive()) {
            txn.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }       
}
```

Comment: JDO/JPA perform what operations you give to those APIs, straight away. What the GAE datastore does with them is the issue not the persistence API, as looking at the LOG would tell you. And I think you mean CRUD (create, read, update, delete). CURD is like jam to put on your toast!

Comment: sorry yes it is CRUD :D when i check console of eclipse it shows me that message after any CRUD operation 
Nov 15, 2013 6:01:03 AM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$PersistDatastore persist
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 38 ms

Comment: I said the LOG, as in log4j or java.util.logging. Tells you piles of things, when you configure it for DEBUG level

Comment: i am not logging anything. also i didn't get any exception or warning msg.

Comment: You aren't logging anything but your chosen persistence mechanism is (as its documentation tells you). It generates a log file. You either debug your problem by looking at it, or treat it all like a black box and your problems remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've encountered is known as [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency): after you make changes to entities (=delete), the indexes are updated asynchronously. This means that delete operation returns, but indexes are not yet updated. Since query relies on indexes it will show deleted data until indexes are finally updated.

There is a [series of articles](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview) if you want to learn how datastore works under the hood.

Comment: so how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @WaqasAli Either your code waits until your entities become consistent (by themselves) or you redesign your datastore entities' relationships and your query code (as pointed to in Peter's links above) in order to obtain instantly correct query results. Of course, a datastore redesign may have knock-on effects wheich you may not want. GAE/J JDO datastore design can be critical for apps.